# I need to consume an ocx for voice recording and playblack

Tags: vb6, ocx, voice-recording, xbase

The current ocx controls I'm using for voice recording and playback are not compatible with Windows 7.  I'm already feeling the pressure to produce a Windows 7 compatible version of my software.  The author has already stated that he is not planning to write a Windows 7 compatible ocx.

I work from xharbour so I need to consume an OCX or write the whole thing (which I'd like to avoid and don't even know where to start).  My basic needs are (1) to record dictation from the microphone with methods to pause and vox preferably, (2) save to file, (3) and later playback with methods to ff and rew.

Thank you,

Reinaldo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this activeX that seems to works:  http://www.download3k.com/Software-Development/Active-X/Download-Active-Audio-Record-Component.html

Reinaldo.